# Delete 3 lines before match, 1 line after match, excluding matched line with sed

Tags: sed

I want to delete `if` around `setenv sd_ROOT` using sed -i, print other lines as usual. I know, a way with awk

```
if {[string match blr* [uname nodename]]} {
 puts stderr "version sd_root_2013_11_04 does not exist"
} else {
  setenv sd_ROOT /tools/sd/sd_root_2013_11_04
}
```

expected Output:

```
setenv sd_ROOT /tools/sd/sd_root_2013_11_04
```

Comment: why doesn't the `awk` solution work?

Comment: I have apply this command on all files in a directory, `awk` doesn't support edit-in-place. I have to wrap `awk`, to do this, so I prefer `sed`

Comment: GNU awk 4.* supports inplace editing, just like GNU sed does. `awk -i inplace 'script' file`. Even if it didn't though, don't create inappropriate sed scripts just to avoid creating the tmp file yourself with `cmd file > tmp && mv tmp file`.

Answer (score 0):

Can be done with `sed`, but is pretty ugly:

```
sed -n '1{N;N;x;n}; /setenv/{N;s/.*//;h;n}; {H;x;s/^\n//;P;s/^[^\n]*\n//;x}; ${x;p}'
```

Comment: Please explain this. I have used it, but did not give expected output